# Backspacing Spanned text alters HTML tags?

Tags: android, html, string, tags, spanned

I added bolded text to an edittext field in my Android app. If the bolded text inserted is two or more words, like "words words", it will be tagged in HTML as "<\b>words words</b>". However if I backspace say the s in words, the tag is changed to "<\b>words</b>\ word</b>". Anybody know why this is? Thanks

(I add forward slashes in bold tags to show the tags instead of stack overflow changing them to bold text)

EDIT:

This is the code that adds bolded text to the edittext box.

```
            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("Add Field",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            field[y] = input.getText().toString();

                            moreText = "<b>" + field[y] + "</b>";

                            Log.d("ADebugTagMoreText", "Value: " + moreText);


                            Text = story.getText();
                            Text = Text.replace(start, end, Html.fromHtml(moreText));

                            Log.d("ADebugTagText", "Value: " + Text);

                            storyText = Text;
                            story.setText(storyText);
```

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I posted some, let me know if you need more

Comment: you are deleting s thus resulting to **words word**

Comment: whoops I'm so sorry, I didn't realize stack overflow automatically used my bold tags and doesn't show them. I meant to show <b>words words</b> and then this after <b>words</b><b> word</b>